# Why does this result in FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am relatively new to Node JS, but I got a kind of error that I have never seen before. It does not have a stack trace like other errors I have seen in the past.

```
Promise.all(hasInitialScrapeCompleted).then(() => {
  console.log("The data after the first scrape is: ", allData);
  while (true) {
    allData.forEach((item) => {
      let x= scrapeInfo(item.url);
      x.then((data) => {
        if (data.sizes === item.availableSizes) {
          console.log("The sizes for: ", item.url);
          console.log("are equal. Attempting to track a new product");
        } else {
          console.log("There is a change in the available sizes.");
          item.availableSizes = data.sizes;
          console.log("Sending notification now...");
          sendNotification(item.url);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I am trying to iterate over an array of objects (allData) with each one containing a URL by using the forEach() method. The scrapeInfo() method does this asynchronously through first returning a promise and once the promise is returned it evaluates the information it got against the array of objects (allData). If there is a change it will send a notification to the user through the sendNotification() which is yet to be implemented, but will also have to be asynchronous. I noticed that my RAM usage spiked to 2GB+, which for this kind of application is completely overkill.

I suspect it happens because the while(True) loop creates new promises faster than they can be resolved, but I can not think of a different way of implementing this. I am used to synchronous programming, so this kind of logic works in synchronous programming, but I am unsure how it should be implemented asynchronously.

Here is the full error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[18112:00000157602690A0]    42266 ms: Scavenge 2034.1 (2048.1) -> 2025.5 (2048.9) MB, 5.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.152, current mu = 0.114) allocation failure
[18112:00000157602690A0]    42277 ms: Scavenge 2034.8 (2048.9) -> 2026.2 (2049.9) MB, 5.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.152, current mu = 0.114) allocation failure
[18112:00000157602690A0]    42288 ms: Scavenge 2035.4 (2049.9) -> 2026.8 (2062.4) MB, 5.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.152, current mu = 0.114) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF79B18B3BD]
Security context: 0x02fd036c08d1 <JSObject>
    1: new Set(aka Set) [000002FD036D4031](this=0x02fb73f40591 <the_hole>,0x005466fc56d9 <JSArray[0]>)
    2: ConstructFrame [pc: 00007FF79B10B9FA]
    3: resolvePluginDependencies [0000037CAAAD3D11] [C:\Users\user\node_modules\puppeteer-extra\dist\index.cjs.js:~270] [pc=0000014D3FE1FC67](this=0x017b8465c949 <PuppeteerExtra map = 0000028FFB2C1839>)
    4: ...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF79A575EBF napi_wrap+114095
 2: 00007FF79A520B46 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+66998
 3: 00007FF79A521946 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+70582
 4: 00007FF79AD36E4E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF79AD1EF21 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833
 6: 00007FF79ABEB18C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
 7: 00007FF79ABF63C0 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
 8: 00007FF79ABF2EE4 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3204
 9: 00007FF79ABE86E3 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
10: 00007FF79ABEEF74 v8::internal::Heap::GlobalSizeOfObjects+212
11: 00007FF79AC2507B v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts+907
12: 00007FF79A96F999 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+7737
13: 00007FF79B18B3BD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+546637
14: 00007FF79B16EB35 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+429765
15: 00007FF79B10B9FA v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+23946
16: 0000014D3FE1FC67
```

Comment: How many pages are you scraping asynchronously?  You should only keep promises a page at a time, and block on a single page until the promises on that single page catch up.

Comment: I have perhaps 5-10 pages, but I want to continuously loop through them once they are completed, hence the while(true) loop above the .forEach() loop. I am not sure how I can implement this logic through promises though.

Comment: Hm but right now you are re-scraping the pages an infinite number of times, all in parallel...

Comment: Yeah, I realised that after looking at the code for a while. I am trying to think of a way to iterate through the list of URLs forever.

Comment: You could possibly use ``setInterval``.

Comment: "*I suspect it happens because the while(True) loop creates new promises faster than they can be resolved*" - far worse actually, it's a blocking loop that even prevents running the code that could resolve them. It's not like the code on the promise chain is executed in a different thread. What were you trying to achieve with that `while(true)` loop? Once all the data is scraped, there's nothing left to do - do you want the process to start over? What does `scrapeInfo` do exactly?

Comment: The scrapeInfo() returns information using the url argument that is passed to it. It then returns two values in an object. One of them is used to check whether it is equal to the original value in the allData array of objects. I need a while true loop so that once a complete iteration through all of the URLs has completed the process restarts.